# Como associar itens duma lista de Strings ao nome do código de uma label em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, lista

O meu objetivo é fazer um jogo da forca.

Basicamente o meu problema é este: Tenho uma palavra dividida em *substrings* para cada letra da palavra, tudo guardado num vetor. Por exemplo:

```
string[] letras = new string[numletras];
for (int i = 0; i < numletras; i++)
{
   letras[i] = palavra.Substring(i, 1);
}
```

Com a palavra dividida nas suas respetivas letras, queria associar cada letra a cada label.

[image: formulário]

Como exemplificado, tenho uma palavra "camisa" e queria dividir as letras para cada *label*. Como cada palavra têm um número de letras diferente, preciso de arranjar um ciclo que me faça isso, ou seja, não posso fazer uma a uma.

Aqui está o código todo do meu programa. Existem partes que tenho de optimizar eu sei, mas o meu problema principal foi o que acima mencionei.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string palavra;
    int tentativas;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Enabled = true;
        textBox2.Enabled = true;
        button2.Enabled = true;
        button3.Enabled = true;

        tentativas = 5;
        label14.Text = Convert.ToString(tentativas);

        var linhas = File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath + "Roupas.txt").Length;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int randomlinhanum = rnd.Next(linhas);
        int indicator = 0;


        using (var reader = File.OpenText(Application.StartupPath + "Roupas.txt"))
        {
            while (reader.ReadLine() != null)
            {
                if (indicator == randomlinhanum)
                {
                    palavra = File.ReadLines(Application.StartupPath + "Roupas.txt").Skip(indicator - 1).Take(1).First();
                    MessageBox.Show(palavra);
                    break;
                }
                indicator++;
            }
        }


        int numletras = palavra.Length;
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(numletras));

        //iNDICAÇÃO DE QUANTAS LABELS O TABULEIRO IRÁ TER

        if (numletras == 4)
        {
            letra1.Show();
            letra2.Show();
            letra3.Show();
            letra4.Show();
        }
        if (numletras == 5)
        {
            letra1.Show();
            letra2.Show();
            letra3.Show();
            letra4.Show();
            letra5.Show();
        }
        if (numletras == 6)
        {
            letra1.Show();
            letra2.Show();
            letra3.Show();
            letra4.Show();
            letra5.Show();
            letra6.Show();
        }
        if (numletras == 7)
        {
            letra1.Show();
            letra2.Show();
            letra3.Show();
            letra4.Show();
            letra5.Show();
            letra6.Show();
            letra7.Show();
        }
        if (numletras == 8)
        {
            letra1.Show();
            letra2.Show();
            letra3.Show();
            letra4.Show();
            letra5.Show();
            letra6.Show();
            letra7.Show();
            letra8.Show();
        }
        if (numletras == 9)
        {
            letra1.Show();
            letra2.Show();
            letra3.Show();
            letra4.Show();
            letra5.Show();
            letra6.Show();
            letra7.Show();
            letra8.Show();
            letra9.Show();
        }
        if (numletras == 10)
        {
            letra1.Show();
            letra2.Show();
            letra3.Show();
            letra4.Show();
            letra5.Show();
            letra6.Show();
            letra7.Show();
            letra8.Show();
            letra9.Show();
            letra10.Show();
        }

        string[] letras = new string[numletras];
        for (int i = 0; i < numletras; i++)
        {
            letras[i] = palavra.Substring(i, 1);
        }


      //Onde preciso de ajuda

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        textBox1.Enabled = false;
        textBox2.Enabled = false;
        button2.Enabled = false;
        button3.Enabled = false;

        letra1.Hide();
        letra2.Hide();
        letra3.Hide();
        letra4.Hide();
        letra5.Hide();
        letra6.Hide();
        letra7.Hide();
        letra8.Hide();
        letra9.Hide();
        letra10.Hide();

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Onde estão aos *labels*?

Comment: São os quadradinhos no meio do form! Apenas estão editadas visualmente.

Comment: mas eu quero saber no seu código, que imagino que é o local onde quer ajuda.

Comment: Já acrescentei o código à pergunta!

Comment: Não, você acrescentou um monte de imagens, isto não nos ajuda nada, coloque o código mesmo.

Comment: como maniero falou, coloque o código, e não faz sentido criar um array de string pra guardar uma palavra. uma string já é um array de char =]. Fora isso depois de colocar o código, acho que deveria colocar as labels na tela em tempo de execução, de acordo com a quantidade de letras dela e, utilizar a Tag do label pra guardar a letra correta é uma opção

Comment: Sou um principiante em programação, não entendo muito desses termos... Mas adicionei o código e espero que resolva a situação!

Comment: @AlexandreNeves Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 2):

Basta fazer isto:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numletras; i++) letra[i].Text = palavra[i];
```

Você vai criar os *labels* mais ou menos desta forma:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numletras; i++) {
    var letra[i] = new Label(); //só a base
    //aqui teria outras coisas
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/Label.cs).

Fazendo assim o código fica absurdamente menor, flexível e mais fácil de dar manutenção e entender.

Eu poderia ajudar mais se tivesse mais partes do código.

Answer (score 0):

No seu

```
string[] letras = new string[numletras];
        for (int i = 0; i < numletras; i++)
        {
            letras[i] = palavra.Substring(i, 1);
        }
```

Você precisar passar o valor para cada `label14.Text`, Ou seja.

```
   string[] letras = new string[numletras];
            for (int i = 0; i < numletras; i++)
            {
                label1.Text = palavra.Substring(1, 1);
                label2.Text = palavra.Substring(1, 2);  
            }
```

Claro você vai ter que fazer de uma forma dinâmica, ou especificar um a um.